# function inside a ngFor loop calls infinitely

Tags: angular

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMP4g.png)
this function returns the username for each order.

I am calling this function here in my component.html where for each order ngFor loop runs. [ngFor looping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG8Nx.png)
this keeps looping and calling api infinitely. I would really appriciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

- Please DO NOT post the code as images.

  - You are now expecting people to type in your code for replicating the issue.
  - If the external image host goes down your question is rendered useless.
- You cannot return anything from a subscription. You are passing callbacks to the `subscribe()` function and they cannot return anything.
- Calling a function in template interpolation `{{ }}` or data-binding `[]=()` w/ default change detection strategy would trigger the function for each change detection cycle ergo "infinite" calls.

You either need to get all the info in the controller (*.ts) or use `async` pipe in the template.

- Use `forkJoin` with `Array#map` to fetch the data for all orders in parallel.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
ngOnInit() { // <-- or wherever the `dataArray` is initialized
  forkJoin(
    this.dataArray.map(order => 
      getuserdata(order.user_id).pipe(
        map(data => ({
          ...order,
          data: data
        }))
      )
    )
  ).subscribe({
    next: (array: any) => this.dataArray = array,
    error: (error: any) => { /* handle error */ }
  });
}

getuserdata(userid) {
  const userId = { params: { id: userid }};
  return this._order.getUserdata(userId).pipe(
    map(res => {
      this.userData = res;
      return res.userdata.fullname
    })
  );
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<td>{{ order.data }}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i found my own abit simple way. i stored the username list on an array on nginit and the called the array with index of each ngFor loop and it worked for me.